# Is the data shared between two pods database deployment k8s

Tags: kubernetes, postgresql

I have a structure like shown in the image below: cluster with two nodes and service for the database (postgres).

Is the data shared between those two pods of `postgres` images or is it possible to set it to share data?

This is scenario which I want the answer to:

- Connect to database with host `db.domain.com` (load balancer point me to `node1`)
- Insert 1 (and only) record in table
- Disconnect
- Connect to database again with host `db.domain.com` (load balancer points me to other node)
- List items in table
- Will I get the inserted row from `node1`?

Also if I scale up to 10 nodes, 10 instances of same service will be deployed, so 10 images of `posgres`, do the all share data?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is the data shared between those two pods of postgres images or is it possible to set it to share data?

Each pod has its own filesystem; there is no sharing between pods by default.

With the right storage driver in your Kubernetes clusters, you can create [persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) that are shared between pods. However, this is usually not appropriate for a database, which typically requires exclusive access to its storage directory.

To achieve your goal of having two database instances with the same content, you will need to set up [postgres replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html). In this model, your database instances form a cluster and writes to the primary server are automatically replicated to secondary servers. You can only *write* to the master, but you can *read* (i.e., perform `select` queries) from any of the replicas.

There are a number of operators that will help set up postgres clusters in Kubernetes. For example:

- [Crunchy postgres](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator?tab=readme-ov-file)
- [Zalando](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator)
- [CloudNativePg](https://github.com/cloudnative-pg/cloudnative-pg)